# Class's object becomes null

Tags: c++, class, object, c++11

The object of my class is becoming equal to `nullptr` and failing. I can't seem to figure out why.

I am trying to pass a string as an argument to a constructor of a class which has been defined by another team - `Hello` in this example. `Hello` class has defined a constructor which takes a reference string as an argument.

I am trying to initialise the object of class `Hello` in my class `Abc` and call the function print.

```
class Hello
{
    Hello(const string& email)
    {
        // initialises some values.
    }
    void print();
};

class Abc
{
    struct Options
    {
        string email;
    };

    Abc(const Options& options)
    {
        Hello hl(options.email);
        cout << "h1 initialised";
    }

    void callprint()
    {
        if (h1 == nullptr)
            cout << "NULL";
        else
            h1->print();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Abc::Options op; // for structure 
    op.email = "hello@world.com"
    Abc obj(op); // to initialise constructor of class Abc
    obj->callprint();
}
```

The output I am getting currently is:

```
h1 initialised
NULL
```

I can't seem to figure out why `h1` is becoming equal to `nullptr`. In C++ class objects never become null by default right?

Earlier, I wasn't checking for (`h1==nullptr`) condition and my program was failing. What should I do to ensure that `h1` is not a null object and I can call the print function successfully.

To reiterate, `Hello` class has been defined by another team. I can't modify it. I can make any changes to `main` and `Abc` class though.

Comment: What's `h1`? Where is it declared? Do you initialise or modify it anywhere? Assuming it's a pointer, what's it supposed to point to? Why do you expect it not to be null? Why do you misleadingly print `"h1 initialised"` after initialising a local variable with a different name `hl`, which will be destroyed when the constructor exits?

Answer (score 1):

You should define h1 as member variable. Right now, you create it in body of function(namely, constructor), so its scope is just this function. After function returns, your object gets destroyed.